# Need to exhance a DateDiff for further detail

Tags: php, javascript, date

Currently the code below only gets as accurate as "1 month" for any date difference one month or less. What I'd like it to do is if the difference is less than one month, output how many days - "XX days". Then if it is less than one day, output how many hours - "XX hours".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
function getDateDiff(timestamp) {
    if (null == timestamp || timestamp == "" || timestamp == "undefined") return "?";
    var splitDate = ((timestamp.toString().split('T'))[0]).split('-');
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
    var d2Y = parseInt(splitDate[0], 10);
    var d1M = d1.getMonth();
    var d2M = parseInt(splitDate[1], 10);
    var diffInMonths = (d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2M + 12 * d2Y);
    if (diffInMonths <= 1) return "1 month";
    else if (diffInMonths < 12) return diffInMonths + " months";
    var diffInYears = Math.floor(diffInMonths / 12);
    if (diffInYears <= 1) return "1 year";
    else if (diffInYears < 12) return diffInYears + " years"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with $ptime being timestamp

```
function ElapsedTime($ptime)
{
    $etime = time() - $ptime;

    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                60                      =>  'minute',
                1                       =>  'second'
                );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with my lack of knowledge in this area I can't go with a completely different coding route like this. It would cause me to have to change other areas of code and I wouldn't know where to start. I'm currently stuck with just modifying the original code.

Comment: Ok. But but unless you are just passing a timestamp to a function, it should be just matter of replacing content inside function. But I will post back with same function you have used but with addition maybe after sometime...

Comment: Stuff like '24*60*60' are dangerous: because of DST some days may last 23 hours, others 25. In this case I do not believe you will need 100% accuracy, but keep that in mind!